# Delay showing of collapse in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions, delay, bootstrap-4

How do you delay showing of collapsed elements in Bootstrap 4?

For example ho do you delay showing content of Link href button in the example below?

```
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a>
```

```
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    <div class="card card-block">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus          richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes          anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
    < div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my solution you can use `data-delayed-toggle` and `data-delay` attributes on the trigger element to configure your collapse behaviour:

```js
$('[data-delayed-toggle="collapse"]').on('click', function(e) {

      var delay = $(this).data('delay') || 1000;
      var $target = $($(this).attr("href"));

      window.setTimeout(function() {
        
        if ($target.hasClass('show'))
            $target.collapse('hide');
         else
            $target.collapse('show');
          }, delay);

      })
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-delayed-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" data-delay="300">
    Link with href
  </a>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    <div class="card card-block">
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
      < div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The animation is done via CSS, and the CSS classes are switched using jQuery.

If you just want to delay it a little, use `transition-delay:` on the `.collapsing` class. For example, here is 2 seconds.

```
.collapsing {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 2s;
    transition-delay: 2s;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

But after a while Bootstrap's JS will kick in and apply the `.show` class to the element. So, to further delay the visibility you can also add a delay `.collapse.show`...

```
.collapse.show {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 3s;
    transition-delay: 3s;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/ZbrrAueeLV

Comment: This delays opening and closing  content, what if delay only when opening?

Comment: something like apple.com handle collapsing menu www.apple.com, notice how the button cascade with menu on opening and closing.

Comment: That's a different animation, not a delay.

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to set a delay manually or with another function as well as prevent transition till you are ready

```
var delay = false,delayed=900;
$('[role="button"]') .on('click', function (e) {  
  var $this   = $(this), href
  var target  = $this.attr('data-target')
      || e.preventDefault()
      || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '') //strip for ie7
  var $target = $(target)
  var data    = $target.data('bs.collapse')
  var option  = data ? 'toggle' : $this.data()
  var parent  = $this.attr('data-parent')
  var $parent = parent && $(parent)

 if(!delay){ 
  setTimeout(()=>{delay=true;  $target.collapse(option); 
  delay = false },delayed); 
  return false    
}   

if (!data || !data.transitioning) {
  if ($parent) $parent.find('[data-toggle=collapse][data-parent="' + parent + '"]').not($this).addClass('collapsed')
    $this[$target.hasClass('in') ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('collapsed')
  }

  $target.collapse(option)
})
```