# HTMX and collapse div, laggy transition

Tags: css, django, htmx

I have built an item hierarchy, that renders out all items, subitems, subitem subitems and so on when the parent item button is clicked. I have used htmx for this and it seems to work quite well. At least gets the job done. My desired end result would be to be able to build as large hierarchy as the user wants to and which would still look good and feel great great to navigate in. Now it is pretty much ruined with the poor transition.

What I would like to fix is the transition of the collapse container that subitem is rendered to. Now it works only when collapsing but not when expanding. I guess rendering the data messes it up and when the container expands, it just pops in without any transition. Once the data is there, collapse and expand works as should and the transition is smooth.

Here is the code:

```
{% if items %}
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush mt-3" id="items-list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item items-list-item">
    {% for item in items %}
        <button class="nav-link btn items-list-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_{{ items.id }}"
        hx-get="/items/subitems-list/item={{ items.id }}"
        hx-target="#collapse_{{ items.id }}"
        hx-swap="outerHTML">{{ items.order }} {{ items.name }}</button>
            <div class="collapse" id="collapse_{{ items.id }}">
                <div class="container-fluid subitems-container" id="subitems-list_{{ items.id }}">
                </div>
            </div> 
    {% endfor %}
    </li>
</ul>
{% else %}
<div class="container-fluid mt-3">
    <span>No items</span>
</div> 
{% endif %}


{% if subitems %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <li class="list-group-item items-list-item">
    {% for subitem in subitems %}
    <button class="nav-link btn items-list-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_{{ subitem.subitem.id }}"
        hx-get="/items/subitems-list/item={{ subitem.subitem.id }}"
        hx-target="#collapse_{{ subitem.subitem.id }}"
        hx-swap="outerHTML">{{ subitem.order }} {{ subitem.subitem.name }}</button>
        <div class="collapse" id="collapse_{{ subitem.subitem.id }}">
            <div class="container-fluid subitem-container" id="subitem-list_{{ subitem.subitem.id }}">
            </div>
        </div> 
    {% endfor %}
    </li>
{% else %}
    <span>No items</span>
</div> 
{% endif %}
```

Is there something that can be pointed out I am not getting or is this even proper way to accomplish what I am trying?

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the transition is working, it's just that it is finishing before HTMX has replaced the data, so that the expansion is negligible.

It looks like you're using bootstrap (or something similar) to handle the transition. This is fine if there's data in there, but is obviously causing you problems if you don't want to preload all the data. If loading all the data is an option, that would solve the problem.

Otherwise, simply delaying the bootstrap transition wouldn't be great user experience, alas.

You could try using HTMX to replace the entire container `<div class="collapse" id="collapse_{{ items.id }}">` with another with the same id, but also a css class with its own sliding transition

This may involve changing to hx-swap ="outerHTML" (and I think you have a typo there also - hx-swat)

This is, in principle, the HTMX method described [here](https://htmx.org/docs/#css_transitions)

Otherwise, if you don't mind dabbling in javascript, there's an answer which talks about delaying bootstrap 4 collapses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190632/delay-showing-of-collapse-in-bootstrap).  You could potentially test for an empty set of child divs and delay the collapse if there's nothing there.